# Checkbox doesnt change visual

Tags: android, checkbox

i have an Activity with a LinearLayout, containing a TextView, a CheckBox and a Button.
When i check the CheckBox nothing visible happens, however it behaves correctly. However, when i click on the Button, then the CheckBox is displayed correctly for a moments before the Activity closes(as it should). Also the option is set correctly, so the state of the CheckBox does really change, but it doesn't display the change. Here is my code:

activity_setup_hint.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:background="@drawable/info_box_inset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <de.myProject.util.FontTextView
            android:id="@+id/calint_txt_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="@string/setup_hint"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <de.myProject.FontCheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/dont_show_hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="false"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_checkbox_button"
        android:drawablePadding="50dp"
        android:text="@string/show_hint"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        />


    <de.myProject.util.FontButton
        android:id="@+id/start_but_calibrate"
        style="@style/myButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onFinishClick"
        android:text="@string/ready" />
</LinearLayout>
```

SetupHintActivity.java

```
public class SetupHintActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup_hint);
    }

    public void onFinishClick(View view) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dont_show_hint);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("dont_show_hint", cb.isChecked());
        editor.apply();

        finish();
    }
}
```

my_checkbox_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_unchecked"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: in xml define android:state_selected also

Comment: can u be more specific pls? in which xml and how should i define it?

Answer (score 0):

setting custom images for `CheckBox` doesn't change by `drawable` property..

Use **`android:button`** property for change button states.. and use Drawable file there...

Define custom xml for `CheckBox`.

> **`android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox_button"`**

**Your XML Code..**

```
<de.myProject.FontCheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/dont_show_hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox_button"
        android:checked="false"/>
```

For Better Example : [Create Custom Checkbox With The Use Of Selectors And Shapes](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Checkbox_With_The_Use_Of_Selectors_And_Shapes/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=80&aaid=104)

You Can Set Your Drawables Image By Following way too...

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) 
     {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (buttonView.isChecked()) 
         {
             cb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.my_button_checked,null,null,‌null); // in order to left ,top , right, bottom
         }
         else
         {
             cb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.my_button_unchecked,null,null,‌null);
         }
     }
});
```

This May Help You...

Comment: the problem there is, that i use inset on the the drawable and when i add it as button, the text doesn't align correct with it. That's why i chose to use Leftdrawable

Comment: use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(DrawableLeft,DrawableTop,DrawableRight,DrawableBottom)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calint_txt_msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/dont_show_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox_button"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_but_calibrate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onFinishClick"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: the problem there is, that i use inset on the the drawable and when i add it as button, the text doesn't align correct with it. That's why i chose to use Leftdrawable